# Asp.net gridview insert calculations

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I want to create code where if for example the dropdown list is = to linemen then his monthly salary is = 6000 and I want this to be put into monthly salary column in my database.

Here is the code - with this code I get error in monthlysalary parameters saying

> use of unassigned local variable total

Code:

```
float total;

if (Designation.SelectedValue == "Linemen")
{
    total = 4000;
}

if (Designation.SelectedValue == "Manager")
{
    total = 6000;
}

if (Designation.SelectedValue == "Boss")
{
    total = 8000;
}

string emp = datapayemp.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString);
string command = "INSERT INTO PAYROLL(RegEmpID, MonthlySalary) VALUES (@RegEmpID, @MonthlySalary)";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegEmpID", emp);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MonthlySalary",total);

try
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: i put 'float total' above the if else

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem is: you're **not** initializing `total` to any value - and if the `Designation.SelectedValue` is neither `Linemen`, `Manager` nor `Boss`, then there's never any value assigned to `total`.

You need to give that `total` an initial value, just in case none of the `if` clauses match:

```
float total = 0.0;
```

Also: `float` is notorious for rounding errors etc. - so if you're dealing with **money** values, I would **strongly** recommend to use the `decimal` datatype instead. Same goes for the SQL Server database table: don't use `FLOAT` or `REAL` - use `DECIMAL(p,s)` instead